# tera data how to use write_nos overwrite parquet file

Tags: teradata

I have a sql like this, executing it first time is ok and the second time will be fail. Because the file exist.
How to use write_nos  overwrite parquet file ?

```
SELECT  ObjectSize, RecordCount
FROM WRITE_NOS_FM (
 ON  ( SELECT * FROM RiverFlowPerm_csv )
 USING
  LOCATION('/s3/bigdaxxxxxx.s3.amazonaws.com/RiverFlowPerm/')
  STOREDAS('PARQUET')
  COMPRESSION('GZIP')
) AS d ;
```

Comment: Afaik you can't overwrite using WRITE_NOS

Comment: SO  HOW TO  OVERWRITE??

Comment: Using an appropriate command for the object store, e.g. from s3cmd?

Comment: WRITE_NOS  is designed to write parquet file to S3 storage.  If can't overwrite it, this function is useless. Because the run sql  command second time will fail.

Comment: Write it to a new bucket

Comment: Write to a new  folder will do, too.

Answer (score 0):

You know the bucket name, execute a pre-process to clear the bucket before running write-nos.   I simply do not understand why write_nos cannot make OVERWRITE='True' do what everyone else would interpret the meaning of this option.

Comment: So what is the meaning everyone else would interpret? Drop all the files in the location? Replace only the existing files but keep others?